# Exchange 2016 - customized DSN not working to exchange server

Tags: exchange-server

I created a customized system message with `New-SystemMessage -DsnCode 5.7.900 -isInternal:$false -Language en -Text "<customized rejection text>"`, both in french and english,

I then created a transport rule to reject some specific messages with that new system message and it works quite well.

It works in all cases except... when the sender (the person whose message is rejected) is on an Exchange server. In that case, the remote Exchange server ignores my custom text and rewrite it as `Your message wasn't delivered because the recipient's email provider rejected it.`

any idea on how to prevent that?